# Items in slick slider are not rendered properly

Tags: javascript, slick.js

I have a problem with Slick Slider (js) that is loading the clones of the slides right after the original, so that slide and its clone are shown one after the other (see img).

This is how I initialize the slider on $(document).ready():

```
$('.carousel').slick({
        dots: false,
        infinite: true,
        speed: 600,
        slidesToShow: 2,
        autoplay: true,
        prevArrow: '<div class="slick-prev"><i class="mdi mdi-chevron-left"></i></div>',
        nextArrow: '<div class="slick-next"><i class="mdi mdi-chevron-right"></i></div>'
    })
```

The html code for slides is called via php.

[image: "This is how the slides are shown. The first is the original and the second is the clone"]

Edit:

@EdLucas this is the HTML code:

```
$html = '<div class="carousel" id="'.$client.'">';    
$html .= '<div class="prod" id="'.$id.'">
                                    <a href="'.$offerUrl.'" class="'.$id.'" data-lbc="'.$data.'" onclick="filterClick(event)">
                                        <figure class="prod-image">
                                            <img src="'.$imgUrl['newurl'].'" width="'.$imgUrl['dim'].'" height="'.$imgUrl['dim'].'" loading="lazy" />';
                                            if($fprice != null && $fprice > $price):
                                                $html .= '<span class="discount">'.-floor(100 - $price/$fprice * 100) .'&percnt;</span>';
                                            endif;
                                $html .=                  
                            $html .= '</figure>
                                        <div class="prod-meta">
                                            <span>'.$name.'</span>
                                            <span class="price">'.$offer->price.$currency.'</span>
                                            <h4>'.$title.'</h4>
                                        </div>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
</div>';
```

Comment: It would be helpful to include in your question the slideshow HTML markup generated by your PHP.

Comment: @EdLucas you are right I edited the question.